# Php Vcard shows empty on outlook

Tags: php, wordpress, outlook, vcf-vcard

I am trying to create a vcard link download that creates the vcard on-the-fly.

```
if(isset($_POST)){
header("Content-type: text/vcard");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=" . get_the_title() . ".vcf");
$content = "\rBEGIN:VCARD\r";
$content .= "VERSION:2.1\r";
$content .= "N:Vicon;Barry;S.\r";
$content .= "FN:Barry S. Vicon\r";
$content .= "ORG:sample\r";
$content .= "TITLE:Partner\r";
$content .= "NOTE;ENCODING=QUOTED-PRINTABLE:    =0D=0A\r";
$content .= "TEL;WORK;VOICE:(516) 999-9999\r";
$content .= "TEL;WORK;FAX:(516) 999-9999\r";
$content .= "URL;WORK:http://www.sample.com\r";
$content .= "EMAIL;PREF;INTERNET:bcohen@sample.com\r";
$content .= "REV:TZ\r";
$content .= "END:VCARD";
echo $content;
}
```

the file downloads fine and the file format is correct as well but when opened in outlook, not a single info is imported.

here is the output file of `the_title.vcf`

```
BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:2.1
N:Vicon;Barry;S.
FN:Barry S. Vicon
ORG:sample
TITLE:Partner
NOTE;ENCODING=QUOTED-PRINTABLE: =0D=0A
TEL;WORK;VOICE:(516) 999-9999
TEL;WORK;FAX:(516) 999-9999
URL;WORK:http://www.sample.com
EMAIL;PREF;INTERNET:bcohen@sample.com
REV:TZ
END:VCARD
```

another pre-existing vcard has the exact same info and everything seems to be working when outlook opens that file.

what am I missing here?

Comment: `\n\r`, perhaps? `\r` is just a carriage return, and most everything in Windows-land uses newline/carriage return.

Comment: I cannot believe it.. that was actually the cause of the issue..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$content = "BEGIN:VCARD\n\r";

Solves the issue. thanks to Marc's comment